# cannot use NERDTreeToggle

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I installed NERDTree with Vundle, and applied

```
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

in `.vimrc`.

However, when I pressed `<C-n>`, the software is stuck in command line, I can not find the nerdtree on the left of the screen, Neither can I shut down vim using `q` command.

[image]

How can I fix this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

What Vim is that? Why NERDTree when you already have a nice GUI file explorer?

Anyway…

Your plugins are not loaded (and probably not installed) because all your `Plugin …` commands are in the wrong place: lines 21-24, 26, and 32 should be between lines 14 and 16.

Comment: or a nice split based explorer inside vim (`:h explore`)